# RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

AWS recently notified me I need to upgrade an RDS instance that's using an instance type that's being removed.

So I logged in, and bumped up my instance size from m1.small to m5.large (the smallest they still have), clicked apply, and it gave me this error message:

```
RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.m5.large, Engine=postgres, EngineVersion=9.4.25, LicenseModel=postgresql-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.
```

I tried a few different instance sizes and engine versions, and it gives me the same general message.

Googling the error messages finds me no documentation about which combinations are supported. How do I fix this error?

From [this similar article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-instance-class-error/), I found I can get a list of allowed Postgres versions by running:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine postgres --db-instance-class db.m5.large --query 'OrderableDBInstanceOptions[].EngineVersion'
```

However, I can't find any instance class that lists an engine version shown in the admin console. For example, the UI lists:

```
10.11, 11.6
```

but the command line tool only lists:

```
10.17, 10.18, 10.19, 10.2, 11.12, 11.13, 11.14, 11.15
```

Why is AWS forcing me to upgrade, but not giving me any options to upgrade?

Comment: i will suggest that you should consider to contact aws support directly instead using serverfAult